# How do I store the first line of a URL txt file using nodejs

Tags: node.js

How do I read the firstline of this URL text file `http://redsismica.uprm.edu/Data/prsn/EarlyWarning/Catalogue.txt`
using Nodejs and store it in a string variable?

Comment: Have you tried using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) library?

Comment: Can you write the code as an example? to be honest I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const request = require('request');

request('http://redsismica.uprm.edu/Data/prsn/EarlyWarning/Catalogue.txt', (error, response, body) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const firstLine = body.substring(0, body.indexOf('\n'));

    console.log(`First line is: ${firstLine}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

fetch('http://redsismica.uprm.edu/Data/prsn/EarlyWarning/Catalogue.txt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then( content => console.log(content.split("\n")[0]))
    .catch(error => console.log(error)) // Catching errors
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Plain text is almost always better than screenshots. Those can be very hard to read, especially if you're dependent on a screen-reader.

Comment: there is plain text and screenshot of result.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying post all of it as plain-text. It makes it a lot more usable.